# Duck-Typing in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, terminology, duck-typing

What is duck-typing and how is ColdFusion related?

Comment: perhaps you really mean duck-typing? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ColdFusion allows function arguments to be specified as having type `any`. For this sort of argument, an arbitrary object can be passed in and method calls are bound dynamically at runtime. If an object does not implement a called method, a runtime exception is thrown which can be caught and handled gracefully. In ColdFusion 8, this can be picked up as a defined event onMissingMethod()rather than through an exception handler. An alternative argument type of `WEB-INF.cftags.component` restricts the passed argument to be a ColdFusion Component (CFC), which provides better error messages should a non-object be passed in.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_ColdFusion